# Add incrementing integer to queryset each time an object is touched in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to add an incrementing integer, in this case a unique sequence number ranging from [1,n] where n is the number of sequences in the given schedule.

As the sequences will get updated regularly I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to loop through the following

```
Sequence.objects.filter(schedule=schedule).order_by('start', 'id')
```

and assign the incrementing number to each sequence. Also, where would be the ideal place to implement this method if I want it to run every time a new sequence is created, deleted or a sequence is updating the `start` field. I've been thinking about the `save()` and `delete()` method, however I dont wish to update when only other fields in the sequence is updated.

This is my sequence model

```
class Sequence(models.Model):

    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='sequence number',
        help_text='auto incrementing sequence number',
    )
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Schedule,
        verbose_name='schedule',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sequences',
        help_text='schedule primary key',
    )
    start = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='start date',
        help_text='sequence starting datetime',
    )
    end = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='end date',
        help_text='sequence ending datetime',
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could (for not saying "should") use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) for this.

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled applications to get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. **They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.**

You could then use a function (receiver) for update according to the signal the `Sequence` model is sending (post_save, pre_save, pre_delete, etc ...).

You should not override `save` or `delete` for this. Your logic involves changes to more than one instance, and you should keep save and delete relative to a single instance.

On the other hand, you can use F expression for updating efficiently sequence instances.

You will find a very good example in the docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

## Update:

Ok, In the original answer I pointed out the way to go, now I will show you the whole thing, I was hoping you could figure it out by your self.

*I tried using signals but came to the conclusion that it would be the wrong approach. Signals would be triggered for every save()... Thus triggering an infinite loop.*

It is not the wrong approach, you've used the wrong signal/implementation ;).

According to your requirements there I can tell there is a correspondence:

```
update sequence instance (save)    --->    do not change indices 
delete sequence instance           --->    update indices  
create sequence instance           --->    add incremented index
```

So, we have the signal `delete` and we also have the signal [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) that receives as third argument a boolean stating if the instance has been created or just updated (Did you read the link I shared with you?).

Then...

### Update indices when deleting a `Sequence` instance:

```
@receiver(delete, sender=Sequence)
def deletion_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Since number is incremental we only must update
    # those that are after the instance being deleted.
    number = instance.number
    sequences_for_update = Sequence.objects.filter(number__gt=number)
    # Decrement 1 to all sequences after number. No for loop.
    sequences_for_update.update(number=F('number') - 1)
```

### Update indices when creating a new instance

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Sequence)
def creation_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # We only care about created instances (this avoid the infinite
        # loop you're talking about).
        # Now take the last number.
        instance.number = Sequence.objects.aggregate(last=Max('number'))['last'] + 1
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think about signal to solve my problem. However as it is a two part question I can't accept the answer. I was also wondering about the most efficient way to implement an incrementing field. I have checked out annotations, however I'm not sure if I can "count" across a queryset using these.

Comment: Also, instead of using signals, can't I use implement my manager method in the `save()` and `delete()` method? I'm not using cascading some information across applications, but manipulating objects.

Comment: I tried using signals but came to the conclusion that it would be the wrong approach. Signals would be triggered for every `save()` and currently I'm run `for sequence in Sequence.objects.filter(schedule=schedule).order_by('start', 'id')` with a `save()` in each loop in order to achieve the automatic number I'm looking for. Thus triggering an infinity loop. As far as I know there is no way to run iterations on the database to get row indexes and assign these to a number column in Django. I ended up having a manager that loops through all the objects in the queryset, and adds an index in each.

Comment: @GjertG I've updated the answer to show you the whole thing, I was hoping for you figure it out by your self.

Comment: Ooooh, I see, I must have missed the fact that one gets the created/updated part in the signal. Does the documentation state if it is possible to find what fields are being updated in the instance for the updated part? I'm also incrementing/decrementing the index if the `start` datetime is being changed (thus changing its position in the `order_by()` queryset)

Comment: Yes, you can pass the update_fields to save method, it will received by the signal handler. is in the Docs.